A Laravel PHPunit test that includes a mocked object is not modifying the service provider
I have a laravel site that includes a model object that called Importer that extends
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model  

It has a __construct function that accepts a $name and $type variable.  It also has one function called get_data() that calls on an external API and returns a SimpleXML object or null.  It's involved in a complicated process that I want to test.  During the test process, I want to mock this object so that I can prevent the external API call and return testable data when get_data() is called.  In my Test, I have included the following code:
$this->mock(Importer::class, function ($mock) {
        $mock->shouldReceive('get_data')->once()->andReturn(null);
});

I expect this to mock a return of null when the following code is performed within another object's function during the test:
$import_object = new Importer('Weather', 'Temperature');
$result = $import_object->get_data();

However, I am finding that the original Importer function is still being called.  Why is the Mock not working?
Update ================================
I have also tried
$import_object =  app(Importer::class, ['asset_name' => $name, 'type' => $type]);
$result = $import_object->get_data();

and
$import_object =  app('Importer', ['asset_name' => $name, 'type' => $type]);
$result = $import_object->get_data();

and with
$this->mock(Importer::class, function ($mock) {
    $mock->makePartial()->shouldReceive('get_data')->once()->andReturn(null);
});

and the result is still the same.  The get_data() function in the original class is still called.

Mock is only possible via service container.
Avoid new in Laravel.
$import_object = app(Importer::class, ['name' => 'Weather', 'type' => 'Temperature']);

With this usage, mocking is possible.
It is better to avoid Model inheritance and overwriting __construct().

And mock models at all.

Is there a better way to fake the data coming from a model?

@puklipo I gave this a try, and was sure that it would work, but the original class function was still called instead of the mock.

Maybe I need to turn my model into a ServiceProvider?
